# php foreach last data not print

Tags: php, foreach

In my php foreach loop last data not showing my table

my function

```
/**
 * @param $totals
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCustomHour($totals)
{
    $startMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->startDate);
    $endMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->endDate);
    $data = array();
    $maxload = array();
    $total = 0;
    $hour = 0;
    $day = 0;
    if ($totals) {
        foreach ($totals as $key => $testData) {
            $today = $testData['day'];
            $hourTotal = $testData['count'];
            if ($day == 0) {
                $day = $today;
            }

            if ($today == $day) {
                if ($hourTotal > $total) {
                    $hour = $testData['hour'];
                    $total = $hourTotal;
                }
            } else {
                if ($day < 10) {
                    $maxload["Day"] = $endMonth . "0" . $day;
                } else {
                    $maxload["Day"] = $startMonth . $day;
                }

                $maxload["Hour"] = $hour;
                $maxload["Count"] = $total;
                $data[] = $maxload;
                $day = $testData['day'];
                $hour = 0;
                $total = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

i don't know how this function is working because it written previousely but as of my understand in response below mention

```
Day Hour Count
1   00  11
1   01  10
1   02  13
1   03  18
1   04  18
1   05  29
1   06  25
1   07  13
1   08  23
1   09  31
1   10  30
1   11  30
1   12  22
1   13  21
1   14  24
1   15  29
1   16  29
1   17  41
1   18  13
1   19  16
1   20  19
1   21  18
1   22  8
1   23  9
3   00  7
3   01  18
3   02  13
3   03  23
3   04  17
3   05  24
3   06  21
3   07  15
3   08  18
3   09  31
3   10  35
3   11  28
3   12  23
3   13  21
3   14  23
3   15  31
3   16  30
3   17  32
3   18  25
3   19  17
3   20  11
3   21  17
3   22  14
3   23  6
4   00  9
4   01  13
4   02  11
4   03  19
4   04  19
4   05  24
4   06  22
4   07  24
4   08  17
4   09  31
4   10  33
4   11  25
4   12  26
4   13  21
4   14  26
4   15  25
4   16  27
4   17  33
4   18  25
4   19  22
4   20  21
4   21  13
4   22  11
4   23  3
6   00  8
6   01  17
6   02  12
6   03  21
6   04  21
6   05  18
6   06  22
6   07  20
6   08  28
6   09  29
6   10  26
6   11  28
6   12  23
6   13  21
6   14  25
6   15  25
6   16  31
6   17  37
6   18  20
6   19  18
6   20  24
6   21  14
6   22  10
6   23  2
7   00  9
7   01  16
7   02  17
7   03  14
7   04  19
7   05  16
7   06  22
7   07  19
7   08  21
7   09  31
7   10  36
7   11  28
7   12  25
7   13  21
7   14  24
7   15  31
7   16  34
7   17  27
7   18  15
7   19  26
7   20  13
7   21  19
7   22  10
7   23  7
8   00  9
8   01  10
8   02  15
8   03  20
8   04  25
8   05  20
8   06  15
8   07  21
8   08  24
8   09  40
8   10  27
8   11  26
8   12  21
8   13  21
8   14  25
8   15  27
8   16  28
8   17  38
8   18  12
8   19  29
8   20  12
8   21  19
8   22  11
8   23  5
9   00  10
9   01  16
9   02  10
9   03  18
9   04  21
9   05  19
9   06  19
9   07  21
9   08  22
9   09  35
9   10  29
9   11  28
9   12  25
9   13  21
9   14  23
9   15  25
9   16  35
9   17  32
9   18  19
9   19  19
9   20  24
9   21  12
9   22  11
9   23  6
```

it will check each day count which is highest per day it will return that day values.

So my problem is here everything is working fine but last which means 9th day data not showing

even i try to print day in my else it only print 134678 once enter else loop it will skip last date

my output

```
Day Hour    Count
2019/01/01  17  41
2019/01/03  10  35
2019/01/04  10  33
2019/01/06  17  37
2019/01/07  10  36
2019/01/08  09  40
```

i don't understand what is the problem ?

Comment: _i don't know how this function is working because it written previousely..._ Take a look at the code and find out how it does work?

Comment: I saw this question yesterday.

Comment: I saw that but i don't know how to print highest count in each day

Comment: Try writing the code yourself. You will learn more, and have an actual question to ask when you get stuck.

Comment: ok @Andrew can you please help me how to find largest count in each day

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Is there in the code where you are modifying `$totals` by referencing? kinda like `foreach($totals as &$testData)` if so change the variable names or do it differently.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand can you please give a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a method that should return highest count per day:

```
function getCustomHour($totals) {
    $startMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->startDate);
    $endMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->endDate);
    $data = array();
    $maxCount = array();

    if (empty($totals)) {
        return $data;
    }

    foreach ($totals as $key => $testData) {
        $today = $testData['day'];
        $count = $testData['count'];
        if (empty($maxCount[$today]) || $count > $maxCount[$today]) {
            $maxCount[$today] = $count;
            $data[$today]['Count'] = $maxCount[$today];
            $data[$today]['Hour'] = $testData['hour'];
            if ($today < 10) {
                $data[$today]["Day"] = $endMonth . "0" . $today;
            } else {
                $data[$today]["Day"] = $startMonth . $today;
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: still same you added {} apart from no change on this

Comment: hm.. well, I removed the $data[] assign stuff from out of the else case into the loop.

Comment: yes that won't work it will print all data rather then highest count

Comment: maybe try this, it should work properly I think, have not tested it. good luck.

Comment: in this day show array and count show 2,019 for all count

Comment: Hey actually it's working but table header i can't able to set like  Day Hour    Count

Comment: previousely response comes like this 

"Day Hour    Count
2019/01/01  17  41
2019/01/03  10  35
2019/01/04  10  33
2019/01/06  17  37
2019/01/07  10  36
2019/01/08  09  40"

Comment: but now 
2019/01/01  17  41
2019/01/03  10  35
2019/01/04  10  33
2019/01/06  17  37
2019/01/07  10  36
2019/01/08  09  40

it print this there is no header like Day etc ..

Comment: I don't know how you are using it/parsing it.. I'm sure it can work like this also because output is similar. Paste a code example and I can look over it later.

Comment: Can you please check my question in my output the data and table is coming fine but header label not coming